# What is the 1393th number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the 1393th number in this string??

> 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5........

Could you explain me how to answer this kind of questions .

Comment: Do you see a pattern arising in this particular sequence or absolutely not?

Answer (score 4):

Note: The $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^{th}$ number is $n$ and the $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1)^{th}$ number is $n+1$.

What we want to do is find the inverse of $x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

After solving the quadratic, you get $n=\frac{\sqrt{1 + 8 x}-1}{2}$ (take the positive root, of course).

Now plug in $x=1393$. and we get $n=52.2$. So the $1393^{th}$ number is a $53$ (round up).

So in general the $x^{th}$ number is $\lceil \frac{\sqrt{1 + 8 x}-1}{2} \rceil$.

Comment: Tnx a lot  it could be the best answer

Comment: @SamJahangiri You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Keep on subtracting $1, 2, 3, \dots$ from $1393$ until the remainder is larger than or equal to the next number to be subtracted. The next number to be subtracted is the $1393$-th number.

That is, find the largest $n$ such that

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n i < 1393$$

Answer (score 1):

The last $1$ is at position $1$.

The last $2$ is at position $1+2 = 3$.

...

The last $n$ is at position $1 + 2 + ... + n = \frac 12 n(n+1)$.

Solve $\frac 12 n(n+1) = 1393$. All you need is an approximation.

Since for larger $n$, $n\approx n+1$, you can state $n^2 \approx (1393)(2) = 2786$ giving $n \approx 52$.

In fact $n$ is slighty over $52$. The final $52$ will be at position $\frac 12 \cdot 52 \cdot 53 = 1378$.

And the remaining $53$ positions (up to position $1431$) will be repeats of the number $53$.

So the answer is $53$.

Answer (score 0):

```
It will be a bit easier if we start counting at 0.

start  0  1     3        6          10             15
index  0, 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 12 14 15 16
number 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,........

 The number 1 starts at index  0 = 0
 The number 2 starts at index  1 = 0+1.
 The number 3 starts at index  3 = 0+1+2
 The number 4 starts at index  6 = 0+1+2+3
 The number 5 starts at index 10 = 0+1+2+3+4
 The number 6 starts at index 15 = 0+1+2+3+4+5
 The number n starts at index      n(n-1)/2.

So we need to find the largest n such that
    n(n-1)/2 ≤ 1392 (because we started counting at 0 instead of 1)
    n(n-1) ≤ 2784
```

Since  $n(n-1) = 2784$ is about $n^2 = 2784$, a good guess for $n$ would be $\lfloor \sqrt{2784} \rfloor = 52$

We compute
\begin{align}
   52\times 51 &= 2652\\
   53 \times 52 &= 2756\\
   54 \times 53 &= 2862\\
\end{align}

```
 So  the number 53 starts at index 53(53-1)/2 = 1378
 and the number 54 starts at index 54(54-1)/2 = 1431.

 That means that the 1379th number is 53
 and the 1432th number is 54.

 So the 1393th number is 53.
```